# What is the size of RLMInt?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I'm curious what the size is of `RLMInt` in Realm.

What is the size of `RLMInt` in Realm? Is it an `int`, `long`, or platform dependent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSNumber<RLMInt>` properties can store all values that fit in a signed 64-bit int.

The actual space used on disk depends on what values are actually stored in the properties, as Realm dynamically adjusts it to use the smallest size int possible (all the way down to zero bits per property if all of the values are 0).